# Docker returns ModuleNotFoundError despite $PYTHONPATH being set

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I have a docker with airflow, when trying to run a python script using Airflow it returns:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'others'
```

If I print `echo $PYTHONPATH` I get `:/libraries:/database_libraries:/others`
Printing `whoami` I get: `airflow`

All three statements running in a DAG.

If i get in the docker machine and these statements through Bash I get:

```
whoami: --> airflow
echo $PYTHONPATH: --> :/libraries:/database_libraries:/others
python script.py(previously did: cd /usr/local/airflow/dags) --> ModuleNotFoundError
```

It neither works using python in terminal, same error.
But it works If I do `cd /` and then `python script.py` (well, it returns Permission denied from a logger file created by the script itself)

could both problems be related to permisions?
I don't have the pwd of the root user because docker is created `FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1`

**Edit**

sys.path has the following:

```
/
/libraries
/database_libraries
/others
/usr/local/lib/python36.zip
/usr/local/lib/python3.6
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

**Edit 2:**

**Dockerfile**

```
#Base image
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1

#Impersonate
USER root

#Los automatically thrown to the I/O strem and not buffered.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/libraries"

WORKDIR /
#Add docker source files to the docker machine
ADD ./docker_resources ./docker_resources
#Install libraries and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
RUN pip install --user psycopg2-binary
RUN pip install -r docker_resources/requirements.pip
```

**EDIT 3**
I know whats happening, but dont know how to fix it.
If I do:

```
cd /usr/local/airflow
python
 import libraries
```

It fails, with `ModuleNotFoundError`
But if before that I move libraries folder to `/usr/local/airflow`
and then do that, it works. Despite not changing PYTHONPATH. So it seems that the import search the folder in the current directory.

How to fix it?

The script do: `import utils` which maybe is that it doesnt understand the root specified into PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Maybe you have more than one python installed? check `sys.path`

Comment: @Ivan I just edited the question with that info

Comment: Can you also show your Dockerfile?

Comment: @BrunoLubascher just added it

Comment: @Maik have you tried removing the statement `USER root` from the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

`PYTHONPATH` is set to `/libraries`, so python is looking for:

1. `/libraries/libraries.py`
2. `/libraries/libraries` folder with `init.py`

I set `PYTHONPATH` to `/`, so it looks for: `/libraries.py` or `/libraries` with `init.py`